# Change Display Value in Radio Button Column

Tags: radio-button, lookup, powerbuilder, datawindow

I have a radio button in datawindow and I want to change the display value using codes depending on command button I'll click. Is it possible? What function I can use? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is some code:

```
string ls
dw_1.insertrow(0)
dw_1.setredraw(FALSE)
// get the current values
ls = dw_1.describe("blue_1.values")
//ls is 'Red~tR/Blue~tB/Orange~tO'
// change the values
ls = dw_1.modify("blue_1.values = 'Green~tG/Teal~tT/Brown~tB'")
dw_1.setredraw(TRUE)
```

The radiobutton column in this example is "blue_1".